# How can I maximize a split window?

Tags: vim, split, editor

Invoking `:help` in Vim, I got the help manual page with split window. I want to maximize the help manual window and close the other window.

How can I do this? What is the Vim command to do this?

Comment: For people using NeoVim try: `vim.cmd("wincmd ...")`, where `wincmd` is equivalent to `<C-W>` in Vim, and substitute `...` for `_`,`|`,`h`, ..., etc. Linked to an answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29923368/5290519

Answer (score 98, accepted):

With ***:help [topic]*** you open up a topic that interests you.
***Ctrl-Wo*** will minimize the other windows (leaving only the help window open/maximized).
*(Ctrl-Wo means holding Ctrl press W, and then o)*

Comment: or , :only will do the job.

Comment: From the editing file how can i get back to the help manual after doing CTRL+W o ?

Comment: @guru: `C-w`, `^`, `:buf OtherFile.txt`, `:sbuf Otherfile.txt` etc. (see help for `wincmd`, `switchbuf` for details). The funy thing is that my (IMHO) _correct_ answer hadn't been given yet...

Comment: @sehe - Your answer suggest using tabs. Not only were tabs not in the question, good vim practice is usually avoiding them.

Comment: @ldigas: that is a (surprising) opinion. Unless you quote a reputable source, I'm going to hold that as your personal preference, really. I'm usually not using them, but I've recently found I'm using them for thigns like this (maximizing a sidebuffer temporarily; doing power stuff like having multiple disjoint side-by-side diffs in a single vim session). Tabs are also a usability miracle with `gvim --remote`. I'm always using `se guioptions=agim` though because I prefer console-like rendering of tabs.

Comment: @sehe - No it is (well, it is in a way, since everything is) not a personal preference. Vi/Vim was originally designed to work with the concept of buffers and windows. Tabs were added only later; Moolenaar was not expecially enthusiastic about them, but a lot of people demanded them, so in they went. You can find the relevant messages on Vim's archives (somewhere, if memory serves, around 2006 but I could be wrong by a year or two). But, I'm not saying they aren't practical sometimes, nor that you should shop or start (or whatever) using them.

Comment: this will close other windows, and if you have one or more windows where you have made changes and not saved, then this will not work - also I think question is about maximizing window to work for a short time in that state and then later on return to previous state -- by closing all windows then you will have to use your session file or manually open all other windows to get back

Comment: I quote `JohnBeckett` which says *To open the current window in a new tab with the cursor in the same place, enter  `:tab sp` which splits the current window into a new tab. To close the current window, press `Ctrl-W` then `c`.* That will close the newly opened tab.` from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_window_and_return_to_previous_split_structure

Comment: `command! -nargs=1 -complete=help H h <args> | only` .

Setting this in your .vimrc let's you use `:H` as you normally would `:h`, but automatically does the `Ctrl-W-o` combo.

Answer (score 170):

You can employ <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (*that's a capital `T`*) to move any open window to its own tab.

As mentioned by others <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> to maximize within the current tab/window layout (while respecting min height/width settings for various other windows).

(<kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> resizes all windows to equal size, respecting the minimum height/width settings)

**Edit** To the comment

1. start vim (e.g. `gvim /tmp/test.cpp`)
2. invoke help `:help various-motions` - opens a split window
3. move help into separate tab maximized: <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>
4. *enjoy reading the fine manual* :)
5. move the help back into the original tab:

   ```
   mAZZ<C-w>S`A
   ```

   - mA: set global mark A
   - ZZ: close help buffer/tab
   - <kbd>C-w</kbd>S: split original window
   - <kbd>`</kbd>A: jump to saved mark A

You can avoid using a mark for normal (non-help) buffers. Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: After getting tab with CTRL+W T how can i get back to the original splitted windows ?

Comment: @guru: just switch tabs as always (use `Ctrl-PgUp`, `Ctrl-PgDown` or `:tabnext`, `:tabprev`). To close the new (e.g. help) tab, use `ZZ`, `Ctrl-W, C`, `:q`, `:clo`, `:tabclose` or any other way you usually close windows/tabs

Comment: No, that was not the question. Suppose you have two tabs, now you want no tabs, you want that two buffers as splitted windows. Is there any one command to do this ?

Comment: Editing question with general procedure. (_I wish to add that the tone of your comments may come across rather unfriendly. In written language, `"No, that was not the question"` may sound as a reprimand. I'm sure you don't mean it badly_)

Comment: @guru: answer is updated. It was a bit trickier than expected since help buffers are _special_ (and you cannot use `:sbuf` like I'd normally prefer). Hope this helps

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for! Whereas other options like `C-w O` close all windows except one, `C-w |`  really mazimaze current window.

Answer (score 64):

You can expand a window to its maximum size using <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> (underscore). The final size of the expanded window will be constrained by the value of the `winminheight` option. When you close the help window, your previous window(s) will be restored to their former sizes.

Comment: `Ctrl+W o` *closes* the other windows, so they're gone. That's why I use `Ctrl+W _`.

Comment: How can i get back the original two splitted windows with the editing file and with the help manual ?

Comment: The `Ctrl+W =` command resizes windows so they are all roughly the same size.

Comment: For vertical splits, you'll want to use `Ctrl+W |`.

Comment: This is way better than closing all other open files using <C-w>o. Kudos!

Answer (score 28):

I prefer to use tabs for that. Use

```
:tabedit %
```

to open a file maximized in a new tab, once you are done return to the old setup with all windows using

```
:tabclose
```

I find this the ideal solution as this works together with `:cw` and the Tagbar plugin. Taken from: [vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_window_and_return_to_previous_split_structure)

Comment: Thanks for this easy & simple suggestion! You can also just `:q` to close the tab once you're done with it to get back to your previous tab & layout

Comment: Thank you so much Azrael3000, you are the guy!

Answer (score 15):

I like to use 'M' to maximize and 'm' to minimize.

It won't look great as it'll shrink all the other open windows that are in the same buffer, but I found it to be more useful when dealing with tabs. So for instance, instead of opening a new tab for that file then having to close it after you're done with it or want to minimize it.

```
nnoremap <C-W>M <C-W>\| <C-W>_
nnoremap <C-W>m <C-W>=
```

The reason for nnoremap is that I don't care about recursive mapping, but just map should also work.

Comment: If you use `nnoremap <C-W>M <C-W>\|<C-W>_` (without the space after `|`), then the cursor won't move by 1 on each maximize.

Comment: I like this using backslash (`nnoremap <C-W>\ <C-W>\|<C-W>_`). It feels natural with the default bindings `|`, `_`, and `=`.

Answer (score 9):

Install the plugin [vim-maximizer](https://github.com/szw/vim-maximizer), then you can maximize the current window and restore with `F3`

Answer (score 7):

You can get help window in full size without closing/resizing any other windows by using

```
tab help {topic}
```

This will open help window in a new tab, other windows will be left as-is (really resized so that tabline can be shown, but this is only one additional line above). You can close help as usual: at least `:bw<CR>` and `<C-w>c` work for me closing new tab as well.

Answer (score 5):

#### Plugin *ZoomWin*

by *Charles Campbell*

This plugin remaps

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>

to do both: maximize and restore previous layout.

This plugin can be downloaded from two locations

- https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=508 (v24)
- http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#ZOOMWIN (v25)

Comment: `v25n` can be found in [this repo](https://github.com/drn/zoomwin-vim/), and for `vim-plug` users, use: `Plug 'drn/zoomwin-vim'`.

Answer (score 3):

To get just the help up, then close the other window, do this: `:help`<kbd>CTRL-W</kbd><kbd>CTRL-W</kbd>`:close`. Then you'll have just the help up.

Answer (score 3):

Somehow the ZoomWin plugin did not work at all for me, I now see there are other plugins but I already wrote this and gives me the exact effect I wanted <strike>(with a minor quirk detailed below)</strike>:

```
function! ToggleZoom(zoom)
  if exists("t:restore_zoom") && (a:zoom == v:true || t:restore_zoom.win != winnr())
      exec t:restore_zoom.cmd
      unlet t:restore_zoom
  elseif a:zoom
      let t:restore_zoom = { 'win': winnr(), 'cmd': winrestcmd() }
      exec "normal \<C-W>\|\<C-W>_"
  endif
endfunction

augroup restorezoom
    au WinEnter * silent! :call ToggleZoom(v:false)
augroup END
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>+ :call ToggleZoom(v:true)<CR>
```

Use the mapped key (Leader and + in my case) to toggle between maximized / previous layout. If you change to another split in the same tab, maximization turns off.

If you change tabs, the split stays maximized<strike>, although somehow it won't cover the complete full width anymore, with the width minimized windows gaining back some 4 columns or something. Anyway it works acceptably for me even with that minor quirk</strike>.

**edit:** somehow it works fine now, must've messed up in some way before.

Comment: this is awesome

Answer (score 1):

in your .vimrc, just place

```
nmap - :res<CR>:vertical res<CR>$
```

When you want maximize current window, just press - in command mode. Press = when you want to restore the last status of multiple window

Comment: Nice but = doesn't restore 'last status'.